# VBA workbooks.open to open .xls file runs very slow

Tags: excel, vba, xls

Below is my VBA code:

```
Workbooks.Open filepath\filename & ".xls"
```

But it takes around 200 seconds to open a xls file with size of 3M.

When I replaced the file with other excel version, for examples xlsx,xlsm,xlsb files, it takes only a few seconds which is acceptable.

I tried to turn certain excel functions off at the begainning of macro, but still it didnot help.

I also tried to open the xls file manually, it takes around 20-30 seconds, far less than 200 seconds.

Please can someone tell me why and help to sove the problem?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason i can't determine, but as your question the reason somewhere the content of the Excel sheet. VBA does a lot of other functionalities besides opening the workbook. If it takes for Excel 30 sec this can be the reason. If your sheet contains a lot of calculation and other tasks while opening the workbook.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the xls file is sent by third party.  And I dont know why the code runs slower than manual click to open the file. BTW, it is opened in compatibility mode.

Comment: Try to locate the place of the delay. Disable the macros while loading. With this program can check the loading time of the critical file. This is a link to a snippet which measure the loading time of a file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-yjJjGiqo5Bq_GyXbDR8TrguzKc1KMDD/view?usp=sharing